# Как соединить четыре int переменные в одну?

Tags: c++

```
    int hours, min, sec, millisec; 
    string str = "00:41:07,342";
    sscanf(str.c_str(), "%02d:%02d:%02d,%3d", &hours, &min, &sec, &millisec);
```

В этом коде из строки извлекаются цифры и дальше нужно их объединить в одну переменную, чтобы получилась к примеру переменная с значением 4107342, а не четыре отдельные hours = 0, min = 41, sec = 07, millisec =342.
А нужно это для сложения этого значения с другим таким же при вводе. К примеру 4107342 сложить с 95617810. Просто можно это решить так :

```
string str_output;
int newtime
sprintf(str_output, "%0.2d%0.2d%0.2d%0.3d", hour, min, sec, millisec);
ntime = atoi(str_output);
```

То есть, получается сначала извлекаются из строки числа в 4 int переменные, а потом эти 4 переменные снова нужно записать в строку, чтобы  их смогла извлечь atoi в одну переменную. Как-то много действий. 
Может можно как-то сразу в scanf записать в одну переменную все числа или же если нет, то просто соединить эти 4 переменные в одну? То есть, чтобы значение этих переменных не складывалось между собой, а шло последовательно. Используя битовые операции или другие функции или как-то ещё соединить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно соединить, используя знания, полученные в начальной школе:

```
int ntime = hours * 100*100*1000
                + min * 100*1000
                    + sec * 1000
                      + millisec;
```

Comment: Жестоко:). Я уже и забыл когда что-то большее чем + или - в программирование использовал). Просто при изучение у меня вся концентрация идет на решение проблемы инструментами языка и вот к чему это привело...

Comment: @Flammable, с каких это пор в часе и минуте по 100, а не по 60 минут и секунд?

IMHO правильно (в миллисекундах) будет

     timemsec = millisec + 1000*sec + 60000*min + 3600000*hours;

Кстати, после ввода через scanf() видимо стоит проверять правильность введенных данных.

Comment: @avp, из показанного топикстартером кода следует, что нужно получить не количество миллисекунд, а своеобразную склейку. Получение такой склейки я и показал.

Comment: > А нужно это для сложения этого значения с другим таким же при вводе

Если так, то лучше действительно переводить в миллисекунды, как показал avp.

Comment: потом обратно придется переводить, так как одно значение берется из файла, а другое вводится, так вот нужно соблюдать формат в файле, а в нем не в миллисекундах хранится значение.

Comment: @strol, а как Вы видите арифметику с упакованными в одну переменную (типа int) полями и соблюдением формата в файле?

Или у Вас в файле изначально в минуте 100 секунд?

Comment: @avp,в минуте не 100 секунд в файле,вот ссылка на программу http://pastebin.com/yCDSRZkX и ссылка на файл http://rghost.ru/49429802 
Работает нормально, кроме того, что нету проверки scanf, как вы и сказали. А вот чтобы реализовать через миллисекунды, то я пытался целый день почти, но мне не нравилось как разрастался код и все ровно были изъяны. Наверное с точки зрения производительности игра свеч не стоит. Но конечно хотелось бы увидеть как можно реализовать через миллисекунды. Если у вас будет время, то могли бы модифицировать функцию void set_newtime(), чтобы все с помощью миллисекунд было

Comment: @strol: При сложении чисел в вашем представлении возникнут проблемы:

    50 секунд 000 тысячных + 50 секунда 000 тысячных = 1 минута 40 секунд 000 тысячных
    50000 + 50000 = 100000 (что у вас соответствует одной минуте ровно)

Comment: Жесть, вот сейчас я понял что avp имел ввиду. Не знаю как меня так унесло...

Comment: @strol, я посмотрел на код. Давайте Вы сами его модифицируете. 

А (в комментарии не поместится) в ответе я  напишу несколько функций и пример их использования для манипулирования временем в Вашем формате.

Надеюсь, их будет достаточно.

Answer (score 4):

[@strol](/users/14769/strol), вот эти несколько функций (Си/C++) для работы с миллисекундами

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat millitime.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

struct miltim {
  int hours, min, sec, msec;
};

int tomsec (int h, int m, int s, int ms)
{
  return h * 60 * 60 * 1000 + m * 60 * 1000 + s * 1000 + ms;
}

struct miltim fromsec (int tms)
{
  struct miltim res;
  res.hours = tms / (60 * 60 * 1000);
  int rem = tms % (60 * 60 * 1000);
  res.min = rem / 60000;
  rem %= 60000;
  res.sec = rem / 1000;
  res.msec = rem % 1000;

  return res;
}

int stomsec (const char *str)
{
  int h, m, s, ms;

  if (!str || sscanf(str, "%02d:%02d:%02d,%03d", &h, &m, &s, &ms) != 4)
    return -1;
  if (h < 0 || m < 0 || m > 59 || s < 0 || s > 59 || ms < 0)
    return -2;
  return tomsec(h, m, s, ms);
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int msec = stomsec(av[1]);
  struct miltim sm = fromsec(msec);

  printf ("time is  %02d:%02d:%02d,%03d\n", 
          sm.hours, sm.min, sm.sec, sm.msec);
  if (msec > 0) {
    char buf[1024];
    while (printf("enter: +/- hh:mm:ss,msc > "), fflush(stdout),
           fgets(buf, 1024, stdin)) {
      int mod = (buf[0] == '+') ? 1 : 0;
      char *t = buf + strcspn(buf, "0123456789");
      int msec2 = stomsec(t);
      if (msec2 > 0) {
        struct miltim ct = fromsec (msec2);

        printf ("change to  %02d:%02d:%02d,%03d\n", 
                ct.hours, ct.min, ct.sec, ct.msec);

        struct miltim newt = fromsec (mod ? msec + msec2 : msec - msec2);
        printf ("%s and new time is  %02d:%02d:%02d,%03d\n", 
                mod ? "Add" : "Sub",
                newt.hours, newt.min, newt.sec, newt.msec);
      } else 
        puts ("Bad input");
    }
  }
}

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ millitime.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
time is  00:00:00,-01
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 2:20:40,500
time is  02:20:40,500
enter: +/- hh:mm:ss,msc > - 1:21:0,600
change to  01:21:00,600
Sub and new time is  00:59:39,900
enter: +/- hh:mm:ss,msc > + 0:50:0:0
Bad input
enter: +/- hh:mm:ss,msc > + 0:50:0,0
change to  00:50:00,000
Add and new time is  03:10:40,500
enter: +/- hh:mm:ss,msc > avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Вроде работает, но тщательно не тестировал. IMHO их довольно просто использовать в Вашей программе.

Если будут вопросы, то не стесняйтесь, задавайте.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все получилось.Мне почти ничего не пришлось делать). Вот код http://pastebin.com/FHchk8Uw  
Кстати, хотел бы узнать у вас, это же код написан полностью на Си и конечно он будет работать на С++ и теперь я почерпнул много нового для себя в плане функций форматирования и прочего из вашего кода и теперь буду использовать в написании программ на Си. Но многие считают неправильным, использовать Си в программах на С++. Так вот, хотелось бы знать, являются ли те функции форматирования частью С++ или добавлены для совместимости, если только для совместимости, то какие есть аналоги С++

Comment: Рад, что удалось Вам помочь.

Да, код на Си, и его совместимость с С++ проверена просто компиляцией в g++.

Являются ли printf/scanf частью С++?

Думаю у разных людей будет разное мнение, но IMHO верховным судьей остается компилятор. Если он воспринимает некий код, то это код на нужном ему языке.

Аналоги форматированного IO в С++ [безусловно есть](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/formatirovanie-vvodavyvoda), но на мой вкус все это крайне запутано и практически неприменимо в реальных программах.

--

Тут уже места для развития критики С++ не хватает, так что если интересно - открывайте новую тему.

Comment: Создал [вопрос][1])


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/263710/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2-c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2